How to make a pulley system for a 50ft long tarp
I am looking for some help on the best way, and cheapest to make a pulley system for the outside of a pavilion.
Dimensions are 50ft wide x 104ft long and 14ft high. Along the sides there are post every 8 ft.
The goal is to protect the inside of the pavilion from rain, snow, wind and sun. However, most often the side will want to be open and free.
Options:

Rolls up to the top or drops to the bottom. I have almost played with the idea of curtain style sliding side to side.
Obstacles:
Cost of equipment, or tacks or motors.
Amount of time and work required to open and close system
Strength of system vs storms
Sagging due to long length and weight of tarps
Bunching of tarp at ends.

I can send pictures if needed.
I am open to any and all ideas. Thanks everyone

attach the pictures directly into the question

This question falls into the opinion category ("best") but I'll take a shot at it anyway.
We had bamboo roll-up screens on our screened-in porch to provide privacy for the hot tub. Pretty simple implementation for lifting and dropping, and certainly not particularly expensive compared to other choices.
A quick search shows that Amazon sells products of the same nature as our old screens.
Both images from the linked site:

This photo shows the bottom of the system. One cord is attached at the top, on the obverse side in this photo and remains fixed in place, running under the rolled up section and returns to the top in front, through a locking pulley, with the tail hanging down and/or joining the other lift point tails.

This image shows a set of two lift points. The leftmost tail joins the rightmost one to provide a single location to raise and lower the screen.
For something as large as described, it would be advised to have multiple lift points. It may also be advisable to have a tubular/cylindrical take up spool to which the base of the screen is attached, more or less forcing the assembly to roll rather than to accordion into the lines, and creating a more compact mass when lifted.
For the lift mechanisms, one might consider another Amazon product which incorporates a locking/latching rig.

This device has a disadvantage in that one must access the mechanism to manually trigger the release and there's minimal control of the descent. I'd expect that one could find equivalent release mechanisms with a single line lift/descend/release control, similar to that in bicycle hoist products, also from Amazon:

Note the left hand lift mechanism has a lever through which the cord passes. Similar to old-time window shades, one pulls the lift cord at an angle to either release or engage the lock on the cord.
I have had experience with all of these products, not necessarily from Amazon, but identical in construction and function.
